# Prove from the definition that $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ is complete and separable.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove from the definition that $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})=\{(x_{1},x_{2},...)|x_{i} \in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|<\infty\}$ is complete and separable.

Well, I need help solving this. So to get started, I want to know this: my prompt says to prove this from the definition (but, definition of what)? definition of...the space of square summable sequences...in the natural numbers?  What would this mean, exactly?

Comment: $l^2(\Bbb N)$ which is usually just written $l^2 $, is the set of real sequences $(X_n)_{n\in \Bbb N} $ for which $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}|X_n|^2<\infty$ with the distance from $(X_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ to $(Y_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$  defined as $(\;\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}|X_n-Y_n|^2\;)^{1/2},$  which is finite

Answer (score 1):

$x\in \ell^2$ has the form $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $\|x\|^2 = \sum_n |x_n|^2 < \infty$. For $\epsilon > 0$ there is an element of $\ell^2$ with only finitely many non-zero entries, and those entries have rational components only. To show this, first select $N$ such that
$$
          \sum_{n=N+1}|x_n|^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{4}
$$
Then choose $\{ x_n '\}_{n=1}^{N}$ that have rational real and imaginary components such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_n-x_n'|^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{4}$. Then
$$
        \|\{ x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots \} - \{ x_1',x_2',\cdots,x_N',0,0,0,\cdots\}\| < \epsilon.
$$
Finally, show that the set of all such approximating elements is a countable set, thereby proving the existence of a countable dense subset for $\ell^2$.

Comment: Hello - thank you for responding. What is the purpose of noting the element of $l^{2}$ has "only finitely many non-zero entries, and those entries have rational components only" and that the subsequence has both components? Is it to prove that $||\{x_{1},x_{2},...\}-\{x_{1}^{'},x_{2}^{'},...\}|| < \epsilon$? I think I still don't see how we know that this norm is less than $\epsilon.$

Comment: Also, by "all such approximating elements", I think I can show that both the sequences $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{x_{n}^{'}|\}$ are countable, is this correct?

Comment: @PBJ : Choose rational $x_j'$ for $1 \le j \le N$ so that $|x_j-x_j'|^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{4N}$.

Comment: @PBJ : You can show that the set of sequences with a finite number of non-zero coordinates that all rational is dense in $\ell^2$. Then you argue that the number of such sequences with no more than $N$ non-zero coordinates is countable. And the union of all such sequences is then a countable union of countable sets, making it countable ... and dense.

Comment: Oh; we only want to include the values with rational components for our purposes; we are not saying that all existing possibilities for those sequences only have rational components and there couldn't be any complex parts. Of course - gotcha! Ok...this seems like a useful method for proof for me to remember going forward :) And thanks for explaining the other part; I think i can do it now.

Comment: @PBJ : Not sure why someone -1'd your question, but I'm going to offset that with +1. :)

Comment: Thank you sir or ma'am :) And thank you for helping.